Tf2 dynamic broadcaster (w/ Gazebo)
I want to  publish a dynamic frame, that is child of the base_link of my robot. I follow this tutorial.
However, once this frame is published, it appears to be disconnected from all frames controlled by ros2_control (if I set this as a fixed frame on rviz2 it turns out that I have no transformation with the fames controlled by ros2_control).
Can it probably be a problem of the used timestamp? As timestaemp I use this:
t.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
Maybe I should use the Gazebo sim_time since I work on simulation?
If my questions was badly formulated you can just tell me, I will try to explain it better.
Thank you
EDIT
Here is is the tf tree:

The new added frame is new_frame.

You could try view_frames and explain your tree with the resulting picture.

Hi, I have added the tf tree. Thank you

there is a full tree, so where is your problem?

This is what I get on rviz2: https://i.sstatic.net/AJuYBo78.png if I put the new_frame as the fixed frame

Have a look at the time stamps in the tf: some have sim_time, but the new_frame has the ros-time. Set the use_sim_time parameter of your node, and self.get_clock().now() should have the correct time.

Thank you! It works now
